# Why isn't my nested association loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have the following models: Mainline -> Release -> Overlay. I'm trying to get all the overlays for a mainline in one eager-loaded query.

(This is a database that was initially started using Entity Framework on SQL Server, so I have the added complication that the keys are not Rails-standard.)

mainline.rb

```
class Mainline < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'MainlineID'
  has_many :releases, foreign_key: 'Mainline_MainlineID'
  has_many :overlays, through: :releases
end
```

release.rb

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'ReleaseID'
  belongs_to :mainline, foreign_key: 'Mainline_MainlineID'
  has_many :overlays, foreign_key: 'Release_ReleaseID'
end
```

overlay.rb

```
class Overlay < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'OverlayID'
  belongs_to :release, foreign_key: 'Release_ReleaseID'
end
```

I can do the following in the Rails console:

```
m = Mainline.where(MainlineID: 2025).includes(releases: :overlays).where.not(overlays: { Version: nil }).first
```

Which gives me the following SQL, which is correct. I can run this in SQL Server Management Studio and get the correct results.

```
  SQL (40.8ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1) [mainlines].[MainlineID] FROM [mainlines] LEFT OUTER JOIN [releases] ON [releases].[Mainline_MainlineID] = [mainlines].[MainlineID] LEFT OUTER JOIN [overlays] ON [overlays].[Release_ReleaseID] = [releases].[ReleaseID] WHERE [mainlines].[MainlineID] = 2025 AND ([overlays].[Version] IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY [mainlines].[MainlineID] ASC'
  SQL (138.0ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [mainlines].[MainlineID] AS t0_r0, [mainlines].[Program_ProgramID] AS t0_r1, [mainlines].[Designation] AS t0_r2, [mainlines].[Lifecycle] AS t0_r3, [releases].[ReleaseID] AS t1_r0, [releases].[Mainline_MainlineID] AS t1_r1, [releases].[SoftwareVersion] AS t1_r2, [releases].[ModuleName] AS t1_r3, [releases].[FirstProductConfigFileVersion] AS t1_r4, [releases].[ProductIdString] AS t1_r5, [releases].[ModulePartNumber] AS t1_r6, [releases].[InterfaceLevel] AS t1_r7, [releases].[CreationDate] AS t1_r8, [releases].[StartBootLoaderVersion] AS t1_r9, [releases].[EndBootLoaderVersion] AS t1_r10, [releases].[ByteOrder] AS t1_r11, [releases].[IndexTableAddress] AS t1_r12, [releases].[Description] AS t1_r13, [releases].[FileNameBase] AS t1_r14, [releases].[ImportedDate] AS t1_r15, [overlays].[OverlayID] AS t2_r0, [overlays].[Release_ReleaseID] AS t2_r1, [overlays].[Version] AS t2_r2, [overlays].[OverlayDate] AS t2_r3, [overlays].[Proposal_ProposalID] AS t2_r4, [overlays].[Lifecycle] AS t2_r5, [overlays].[Description] AS t2_r6, [overlays].[Comments] AS t2_r7, [overlays].[ImportedDate] AS t2_r8, [overlays].[Proposer] AS t2_r9 FROM [mainlines] LEFT OUTER JOIN [releases] ON [releases].[Mainline_MainlineID] = [mainlines].[MainlineID] LEFT OUTER JOIN [overlays] ON [overlays].[Release_ReleaseID] = [releases].[ReleaseID] WHERE [mainlines].[MainlineID] = 2025 AND ([overlays].[Version] IS NOT NULL) AND [mainlines].[MainlineID] IN (2025) ORDER BY [mainlines].[MainlineID] ASC
```

My problem is that I can loop over the releases without hitting the database again...

```
2.2.3 :137 > m.releases
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Release ReleaseID: 126, Mainline_MainlineID: 2025, SoftwareVersion: "40190004_0", ModuleName: "CM23xx", FirstProductConfigFileVersion: "2003.1.1.0", ProductIdString: "BHQ", ModulePartNumber: "9999999", InterfaceLevel: "4.6.0.0", CreationDate: "2015-06-16 00:0
```

But not the overlays...

```
2.2.3 :138 > m.overlays
  Overlay Load (78.8ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [overlays].* FROM [overlays] INNER JOIN [releases] ON [overlays].[Release_ReleaseID] = [releases].[ReleaseID] WHERE [releases].[Mainline_MainlineID] = @0', N'@0 int', @0 = 2025  [["Mainline_MainlineID", 2025]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Overlay OverlayID: 3747, Release_ReleaseID: 126, Version: 86, OverlayDate: "2015-07-30 00:00:00", Proposal_ProposalID: nil, Lifecycle: "Imported", Description: nil, Comments: nil, ImportedDate: "2015-08-24 13:59:44", Proposer: nil>, #<Overl
```

It's generating another query, this time without my condition that Version is not NULL. Why isn't Rails recognizing that I already have the overlays I want included my selected mainline?

UPDATE: Right after posting initially, I tried the following:

```
m = Mainline.includes(:releases, :overlays).where.not(overlays: { Version: nil }).find(2025)
```

Note the change in the .includes(). This gave me what I wanted to see in the console:

```
2.2.3 :066 > m.overlays
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Overlay OverlayID: 3747, Release_ReleaseID: 126, Version: 86, OverlayDate: "2015-07-30 00:00:00", Proposal_ProposalID: nil, Lifecycle: "Imported", Description: nil, Comments: nil, ImportedDate: "2015-08-24 13:59:44", Proposer: n
```

This generates much different SQL:

```
  SQL (657.4ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [mainlines].[MainlineID] AS t0_r0, [mainlines].[Program_ProgramID] AS t0_r1, [mainlines].[Designation] AS t0_r2, [mainlines].[Lifecycle] AS t0_r3, [releases].[ReleaseID] AS t1_r0, [releases].[Mainline_MainlineID] AS t1_r1, [releases].[SoftwareVersion] AS t1_r2, [releases].[ModuleName] AS t1_r3, [releases].[FirstProductConfigFileVersion] AS t1_r4, [releases].[ProductIdString] AS t1_r5, [releases].[ModulePartNumber] AS t1_r6, [releases].[InterfaceLevel] AS t1_r7, [releases].[CreationDate] AS t1_r8, [releases].[StartBootLoaderVersion] AS t1_r9, [releases].[EndBootLoaderVersion] AS t1_r10, [releases].[ByteOrder] AS t1_r11, [releases].[IndexTableAddress] AS t1_r12, [releases].[Description] AS t1_r13, [releases].[FileNameBase] AS t1_r14, [releases].[ImportedDate] AS t1_r15, [overlays].[OverlayID] AS t2_r0, [overlays].[Release_ReleaseID] AS t2_r1, [overlays].[Version] AS t2_r2, [overlays].[OverlayDate] AS t2_r3, [overlays].[Proposal_ProposalID] AS t2_r4, [overlays].[Lifecycle] AS t2_r5, [overlays].[Description] AS t2_r6, [overlays].[Comments] AS t2_r7, [overlays].[ImportedDate] AS t2_r8, [overlays].[Proposer] AS t2_r9 FROM [mainlines] LEFT OUTER JOIN [releases] ON [releases].[Mainline_MainlineID] = [mainlines].[MainlineID] LEFT OUTER JOIN [releases] [releases_mainlines_join] ON [releases_mainlines_join].[Mainline_MainlineID] = [mainlines].[MainlineID] LEFT OUTER JOIN [overlays] ON [overlays].[Release_ReleaseID] = [releases_mainlines_join].[ReleaseID] WHERE ([overlays].[Version] IS NOT NULL) AND [mainlines].[MainlineID] = @0 AND [mainlines].[MainlineID] IN (2025)', N'@0 int', @0 = 2025  [["MainlineID", 2025]]
```

So now I have 2 problems. First, I don't understand why that .includes() syntax works, when everything I've read on the subject makes me think it really ought to be (releases: :overlays), and NOT comma-separated.

Second, and more importantly, my goal is to get 2 more associations to pre-load, and they get hairier. If I can't understand this first example, there's no way I can get the others loaded in. I eventually need to get to the following:

```
Mainline -> Release -> Overlay -> Calibration <- Parameter
```

How would I load all of this data with .includes() in the correct hash/array arrangement? From what I've read, I'd expect .includes(release: [overlay: [calibration: :parameter]]), but nothing I've tried gets me even close. Just attempts to try to add the calibration level get me cross products of the entire database.

And that's just the core set of data I need to get out of a single query. I also need to combine users and ownerships and categories, etc. My core "mainline" has about 17K lines, with about 8 different models involved. I absolutely cannot afford any sort of N+1 query with this application. I must get it all in one go. (I've successfully set it up as a [find_by_sql()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284066/is-it-possible-to-trick-activerecord-into-understanding-it-has-all-the-data-it-n), which gets me precisely the data I need, but I'd like to get it going "the Rails way," so that I can traverse the relationships as expected.)

I've tried playing with .joins(), since that does INNER JOINS, which is what I really need, but it doesn't seem to pre-load the data. I've even tried combining .joins() AND .includes() as I've seen some people do, but now I'm just guessing. I don't understand why what I'm trying, in this first pass, doesn't work, and, until I do, I'm just wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now that I've misunderstood how to reference eager-loaded data. Despite the proper setup with `has_many through:`, you can't skip over a second association and directly access the third inside the eager-loaded data. I'll never be able to reference members of `@mainline.overlays` without incurring another query. I have to reference them as `@mainline.releases[0].overlays[0]`.

The relieving news is that I wasn't insane about the syntax of the includes. I was just using the result incorrectly. But, based on this way of accessing my data, I've changed the query around to make what I'm really interested in (calibrations) the top-level query, like so:

```
cals = Calibration
  .joins(overlay: [release: :mainline])
  .where(mainlines: { MainlineID: params[:id] })
  .where.not(overlays: { Version: nil })
  .includes(:parameter, overlay: [release: :mainline])
```

Then I can loop over `cals` and access the parameter data, which is my first step/concern.

I also see now the role of `.joins()` in limiting my data set based on associated values. My current (limited) result set takes 3 seconds to do this way, compared with my `.find_by_sql()` method, which only takes about half of that, and already includes a lot more models I have yet to include, so I don't know if this is going to work very well, but at least I understand what's going on now.

(Of course, both methods have the problem that, once ~20K lines of data are handed off the browser, the browser takes 10 seconds to generate the table, but that's a horse of another color.)